# hyperlink not working left or right side of jplayer plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am new in building websites and this is my first one. I was moving along great until I finally had the hyperlink to add to the images I placed on the left and right side of  jplayer. The Hyperlynks work only for images that are above or below. Do you have any idea on how to resolve this issue? 
This is the script that initiates jplayer

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var description = '';

        $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            tracksToShow:13,
            autoPlay:false, 

            description:description,
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath:'../plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the page address: http://stevescottcountry.com/music/music.htm

Please help! Thank you so much.

Stefania

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and I am so happy! The right code to isolate the JavaScript above within a div is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var description = '';

    $('div#NAME_OF_DIV').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
        tracksToShow:13,
        autoPlay:false, 

        description:description,
        jPlayer:{
            swfPath:'../plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
        }
    });
});
```